# What is the best practice to create some SSRS report to show info from a list, and show in a webpart in SP 2010?

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SP2010. I have a list with some important info. I would like to generate some report in SSRS. What is the best practice to create a SSRS report with the source from a SharePoint list?

I would also like to show this report in a webpart on a page.

Comment: Do you have reporting services configured with SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Report Builder tool for creating reports. Then choose `SharePoint List` a connection source.

For detailed steps on creating connection source refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633650(v=sql.105).aspx

After setting up connection you can create queries to create data set. Below is a sample query

```
<RSSharePointList>
<listName>MyList</listName>
<viewFields>
  <FieldRef Name="Field1"/>
  <FieldRef Name="Field4"/>
</viewFields>
<Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
      <Gt>
        <FieldRef Name="Field1"/>
        <Value Type="Integer">1</Value>
      </Gt>
      <IsNotNull>
        <FieldRef Name="Field2"/>
        <Value Type="string"/>
      </IsNotNull> 
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query>
</RSSharePointList>
```

After creating the report - You can upload the `RDL` file into a library (You can use Report Library which has features to leverage `RDL` file type). Then create a page and add `Report Viewer` webpart. And set the `RDL` path.